# Javascript get file name and type from path as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a file drag and drop system which returns the whole path of the file as a string `C:\Users\alexr\Desktop\filename.type`. I can remove the home directory so I am left with `Desktop\filename.type`. How can I separate the path to the file (`Desktop`) to equal the variable `path` and the file name and type (`filename.type`) to equal the variable `type`.

I would like an answer is javascript or jQuery (Tho I doubt it will be needed)

> Edit

Expected outcome:

Less say I had the following path `Desktop\Folder\file.txt`

I would like a variable `path` containing `Desktop\Folder`

And a variable `file` containing `file.txt`

Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: So you want to get `filename.type` from the path?

Comment: Yes, I would basically like to split the string into two separate variables. One storing the path and one storing `filename.type`.

Comment: There you go https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: string.split('\\').pop()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const str   = String.raw`Desktop\Folder\file.txt`;
const parts = str.split(`\\`);
const file  = parts.pop();
const path  = parts.slice(0).join(`\\`);

console.log(file)
console.log(path)
```

Note: I am using `String.raw` to preserve the forward slash, you may not need this

Comment: How would I use this if I had my path stored as a string?

Comment: Then just use the string direcrtly

Comment: So replace the variable `str` with the variable storing the path?

Comment: Yes, just check to see if the slashes are preserved, that would be the only thing presenting a problem

Comment: @RobertRocha, Bro I am glad that I have also learnt a new thing from your solution.. But here also from your statement, ..."I am using String.raw to preserve the forward slash"... you have mentioned it as forward slash but It is really backward slash I believe..

Answer (score 2):

You need to split the file path like,

```
JSON.stringify(str).split("\\");
```

Here there is no need to alter you input, if you want to split the string that has backslash, then use,

```
.split("\\")
```

And the snippet as follows,

```js
const str = "Desktop\filename.type";

const res = JSON.stringify(str).split("\\");
const result = JSON.parse(res).split(',');

const path = result[0];
const file = result[1];

console.log(path);
console.log(file);
```

**Edit:**

Okay, here is the reason why I used `JSON.stringify()`, because the string has backslash which ignores the next character after `backslash` so to get actual string, here I have used, `JSON.stringify`.. You can find the difference between both in the below console..

```js
const str = "Desktop\filename.type";
console.log(str);
console.log(JSON.stringify(str))
```

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(str));
```

While you split the actual string like,

```
.split("\\"),
```

would result as a single array of string..

```js
const str = "Desktop\filename.type";

console.log(str.split("\\"));
```

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify`? There is no json to stringify. It's already a string.

Comment: I think he's using it to escape the forward slash

Comment: @mwilson I have updated the answer with reason for this.. Please review it..

Comment: @AlexHawking, I have updated the answer with reason for this.. Please review it.. As you have ```backwardSlash``` you need to do it like this..

Comment: @RobertRocha, Exactly but if I am not wrong it is ```backwardslash``` ..

Comment: Ohhh. Smart. I think it may not be needed in the context of what the OP is asking since the path is already returned and it's a string. Obviously still need to do `.split('\\')`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and for the way to escape the forward slash, this is returning the path `Desktop` but not returning the file name

Comment: Personally I would do a simple str.split('\\').pop()

Comment: @RobertRocha could you post an answer with your method and I will try it

Comment: @mwilson, Again updated my answer, what you would get if we directly using ```str.split("\\")``` on the actual string..

Comment: Just want to understand first, you want a variable that stores "filename" and another for "type"?

Comment: @AlexHawking, What is your requirement then?? What should you need to get as expected output??

Comment: @AlexHawking, I am on the way to office, give me some moment I will update it..

Comment: @AlexHawking, Hope you got right solution which you want from Robert.. I am also learnt new thing called Raw string from his solution..

Answer (score 1):

You can just use string `substring` to get the last index of the slash (since that's a good indicator where the `filename.type` will be.

*The* `\\` *is just to escape* `\`

Example:

```js
function splitPath(path) {
  return {
    path: path,
    file: path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1, path.length)
  };
}

const path = 'C:\\Users\\alexr\\Desktop\\filename.type';
console.log(splitPath(path));
```